# Azure Site-To-Site TrafficSelectorPolicy is not working

Tags: azure-virtual-network

We are trying to set up a site-to-site VPN on Azure. The problem is that we have a larger virtual network subnet say 10.0.0.0/16 and the VPN should only be able to access 10.0.1.0/24 within that range. We set up the connection and it fails due to "Traffic Selector Mismatch".

I set up the connection from PowerShell as follows:

```
$ResourceGroup = [SomeResourceGroup]
$Location = [SomeLocation]

$OnsitePublicIp = [onsite public ip]
$OnsiteSubnet = [onsite accessable subnet]
$LocalNetworkGatewayName = [SomeNetworkGatewayName]
$ConnectionName = [SomeConnectionName]
$AzureAddressRange = "10.0.1.0/24"
$VirtualNetworkGatewayName = [SomeVirtualNetworkGatewayName]

$IpSecPolicy = New-AzIpsecPolicy XXXXXXXXXXXXX
$LocalNetworkGateway = New-AzLocalNetworkGateway -Name $LocalNetworkGatewayName -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroup -Location $Location -GatewayIpAddress $OnsitePublicIp -AddressPrefix $OnsiteSubnet
$IpsecTrafficSelectorPolicies = New-AzIpsecTrafficSelectorPolicy -LocalAddressRange $AzureAddressRange -RemoteAddressRange $OnsiteSubnet
$VirtualNetworkGateway = Get-AzVirtualNetworkGateway -Name $VirtualNetworkGatewayName -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroup
New-AzVirtualNetworkGatewayConnection -Name $ConnectionName -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroup -VirtualNetworkGateway1 $VirtualNetworkGateway -LocalNetworkGateway2 $LocalNetworkGateway -Location $Location -ConnectionType IPsec -UsePolicyBasedTrafficSelectors $True -IpsecPolicies $IpSecPolicy -SharedKey $SharedKey -TrafficSelectorPolicy $IpsecTrafficSelectorPolicies
```

The connection is still rejected and after running troubleshooting on the connection i see the full range is still being referenced.

```
Proposed Traffic Selector payload will be- [Tsid 4e4 , ]Number of TSIs 1: StartAddress 10.0.0.0 EndAddress 10.0.255.255 ......
```

We have multiple setups on the gateway appliance and they work as expected, however this one does not work due to the "Traffic Selector Mismatch".

Should the Traffic Selector Policy not have filtered the published range to 10.0.1.0 to 10.0.1.255?

I will appreciate any help to get this sorted out. Am I approaching this issue completely incorrectly? Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Do you have multiple connections on this VPN gateway? Is there any other Traffic Selector policy overlaps this?

Comment: I do have multiple connections yes. The other connections dont have traffic selector policies set.

Comment: Try to disable or enable BGP in this connection? and what is your OnsiteSubnet IP range? In the statement:`we have a larger virtual network subnet say 10.0.0.0/16`, Do you have a subnet range 10.0.0.0/16 instead of VNet range?

Comment: We have a subnet range of 10.0.1.0/24 that we would like to expose to the IPSec tunnel. This is also the range that we have set up in the TrafficSelectorPolicy. The problem is that it still broadcasts a traffic selector payload of 10.0.0.0/16 and ignores the TrafficSelectorPolicy.

Comment: `If you enable UsePolicyBasedTrafficSelectors, you need to ensure your VPN device has the matching traffic selectors defined with all combinations of your on-premises network (local network gateway) prefixes to/from the Azure virtual network prefixes, instead of any-to-any. ` read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-vpn-faq#does-everything-need-to-match-between-the-azure-vpn-gateway-policy-and-my-on-premises-vpn-device-configurations).

Comment: Yes that is correct and if these policies don't match on both devices the tunnel will not be able to establish. That is why i need to understand why the TrafficSelectorPolicy is being ignored on Azure. I cannot get the VPN up and running because even though I have a traffic selector policy set (10.0.1.0/24) it still proposes the entire virtual network range of (10.0.0.0/16). How do I get the connection to use the traffic selector policy and only propose the 10.0.1.0/24 range?

Comment: @riaankruger Did you make any progress with this? We are defining a similar setup to this at the moment, and I'm concerned that it won't work.

Comment: @NancyXiong I had seen the documentation you point to, but (probably incorrectly) assumed this was highlighting the need for these to match rather than encompass the entire network. Could you point to any additional documentation around UsePolicyBasedTrafficSelectors which confirms it is for the entire network? Also, is this at both ends of the connection or is it just the Azure end?

Comment: @haymansfield I don't know more, you may raise a ticket to MS support.

Comment: For what it's worth, we were able to make this connection with restricted traffic selectors, so it is possible.