# Azure Site-to-Site VPN with Traffic selector policy

Tags: vpn, azure-virtual-network

We are trying to set up a site-to-site VPN on Azure using IkeV2 and a Traffic Selector Policy. The intended policy is from an on-premises network to a subnet of the azure vnet that contains the Local network gateway.
This seems very similar to the question that @riaan-kruger posted in this question [Azure Site-To-Site TrafficSelectorPolicy is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59748766/azure-site-to-site-trafficselectorpolicy-is-not-working) and seems possible but I am unable to get it to work.
@haymansfield you indicated that you were able to get this to work. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: This looks like a follow-up to another question, maybe it would be better to continue the discussion there?

Comment: I would have but I don't have enough reputation to comment and I can't contribute an answer so wasn't sure what the best way to continue the conversation was?

Comment: If you have a variation of a previous question, may I suggest you copy the relevant parts and adjust the text to fit your usecase? That way anybody who want to answer you don't have to read in multiple places to get the full context. Just a suggestion.